# High Charts doesn't show in my HTML page, unless I view the page as a standalone one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to display some information.  The Chart doesnt seem to show in the Div, unless I place the page away from the root.  For example, the below code brings up the chart as expected when saved and opened from my desktop, BUT it shows blank when opened from the root directory of my site (root);

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Election Results | First for Kirkby</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>


<body data-post="free-responsive-html5-businessportfolio-template-amazingbiz">
    <div class="container box_shadow">
        <!--#include FILE="header.html"-->

    <!--page_container-->
    <div class="page_container">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="breadcrumb">
                <div>
                    <a href="index.shtml">Home</a><span>/</span>Election Results
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <section>
                  <div class="page-header">
                    <h2 class="title">Election Results</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div id="container" style="width:50%; height:400px;">

                  </div>


                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <!--#include FILE="footer.html"-->
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/themes/piha/js/top-bar.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/themes/piha/js/bsa-ads.js" ></script> <!--Dynamically creates analytics markup-->   
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated in making this show in the page its meant to show in!

Thanks

Comment: You are including jquery twice :)

Comment: Ahh! Thanks very much Rob! Worked perfectly, cheers mate